# Marking plural of code words

Tags: grammatical-number, programming

In my blog (which is about programming) I often use reserved words from different programming languages.

Like this:

> When column is nullable in both tables, this query won't return a match of two NULLs for the reasons described above: no NULLs are equal.

Here, `NULL` is a programming language keyword.

For numerous reasons, I mark them with `<code>` tag so they are rendered with a fixed width font, not translated into the foreign languages by Google Translate, can easily be seen on the page etc.

In the example above, which would be the best way to mark the plural?

1. `NULL`s
2. `NULL` s
3. `NULL`'s
4. `NULLs`
5. `NULLS`

Option 1 looks ugly on the page (the word and the plural marker are rendered in different colors and fonts)

Option 2 adds a space between the word and the plural marker

Option 3 looks nicest but is not correct

Options 4 and 5 may leave the reader under impression that `NULLS` is a reserved word (which is not true) and this may be confusing. Also, Google Translate would leave the word as is which would be definitely wrong in other languages.

What would be the least of 5 evils?

Comment: I'd suggest using option 2 and fixing the CSS so that it looks right. :-)

Comment: On closer look, you have explicitly *added* a space before the 's' in option 2. Why did you do that? Stop it and all will be fine.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: unfortunately, I cannot fix `CSS` right here :) I added the space to give you the impression of what will it look like.

Comment: But without the space it looks fine. Where is your blog that has such poor CSS that `<code>NULL</code>s` looks like it has an extra space?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: http://explainextended.com , and it looks ugly without the space. I use different color for `<code>`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Definitely don't use an apostrophe or a capital S to pluralize `NULL`.

As a programmer, I'd suggest formatting it as `NULL`s. I think your readers will understand that.

I'd also recommend considering rewriting sentences like that to obviate the need to pluralize `NULL`. For example:

> When column is nullable in both tables, this query won't return a match of two `NULL` values for the reasons described above: no `NULL` values are equal.

Comment: +1. You actively want the reserved keyword to appear different to the plural marker, in terms of colour and font: `null`s is fine. I think it looks *clear* like that, rather than *ugly*. However, I agree it's probably wise to attempt to reword sentences to avoid these plurals where possible.

Answer (score 17):

You don't have to pluralize these code words, because you can always write them as adjectives. For example:

- How to compare `NULL` values
- Do not write too many nested `while` blocks.
- Make sure that you map the `getDatabasePrimaryKey()` methods.

Comment: But why should you? An answer to a problem that says "Do it differently so you won't have the problem" is sometimes useful, but often just annoying. Since we (I and the OP, at least) have no problem with saying "comparing NULLs", why on earth shouldn't we write it? That is how I would write it, by the way.

Comment: @Colin Fine, that's because you're thinking of the "null" case only. The title of question refers to code words in general. "Null" was the example. Do you write "whiles" and "getDatabasePrimaryKey()s"? Btw, I would write "null value" (as many people) but that's not really the point that I wanted to make.

Comment: Good point. I think I would write "while"s (with the quotes).

Comment: The problem with "rephrase to avoid the problem" is that it often only applies to a narrow example. Yes this works for NULL, where the noun form is shorthand for an adjective, but what about, say, `Object` (the class name)? Would you really suggest using "...for all objects of class `Object`" instead of "...for all `Object`s"?

Comment: @res, depending on how the language in question works, either write "for all objects", or rename the class to something more, um, informative.

Comment: `Object` is a built-in class of both C# and Java--renaming is out. "For all objects..." means something fundamentally different than for all `Object`s. My point is that in narrowly technical settings, "rephrase to avoid the issue" isn't always an option.

Comment: @res, personally, I would actually use "for all instances of the Object class" or simply "for all instances of Object". Instance is a word commonly used in Object Oriented programming.