# The whys and the hows

Tags: grammar, idioms, grammatical-number

Are apostrophes needed in this phrase?

> The whys and the hows

I searched for duplicate questions, but the closest I found was in regard to [words inside quotes.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53523/plurals-and-possessives-of-quoted-words)

Comment: If you feel you need them, by all means use them. If not, forbear.

Comment: What John said. There's no universally-accepted position with such things.

Comment: Not sure about whys and hows right now, but [here's a related question for dos and don'ts](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28671/dos-and-donts-or-dos-and-donts).

Comment: Both are plurals, not possessives or contractions. Plus, neither is likely to be mispronounced or misinterpreted because of the presence of the plural -s. Could you explain on what basis you think they might need apostrophes?

Answer (score 3):

I would say no, but I think I would put them in quotation marks. 'The "whys" and the "hows" of apostrophes aren't easy to understand.'

Answer (score 2):

Actually I was searching for something similar today, and I came across [this.](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/when-to-form-a-plural-with-an-apostrophe/)

I think it's quite similar to what you're asking :

> When forming the plural of words and hyphenated phrases that aren’t nouns but are used as nouns sometimes you do and sometimes you don’t:
>
> - I want no ifs or buts.
> - Here are the dos and don’ts of blogging.
> - I’ve written 25 thank-yous.

**BUT**

> I’m tired of all his maybe’s

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: That's an impressive and comprehensive article, thank you for the link.  There _does_ seem to be something wrong with "maybes", but I'm not 100% sure what -- unclear how to pronounce? I'm having an issue with the instruction that "sometimes you do and sometimes you don't" -- not very actionable. Is there a formula or rule at work here?

Comment: no problem, about pronunciation I think it's pronounced "may-bee-z" and I suppose: use the apostrophe with "maybe's" and the rest of the words don't like "buts" and "ifs".. glad the article helped you

Comment: What is the basis for the author of your linked article giving *maybe's* an apostrophe but not the others? Maeve says "sometimes you do, sometimes you don't" but provides no sort of justification or rule for determining this.

Answer (score 0):

In English, apostrophes indicate either possession or omission.

An example of possession might be

```
The cat's bed,
```

Or, in the plural,

```
The cats' bed.
```

(A good example of an omission is in a contraction, such as `isn't` for `is not`."

But an apostrophe is not often (*correctly*) used it English to mark a plural of a regular noun. (However, decades or centuries (80's, 90's, 1500's), and some brands and abbreviations (M&M's, sometimes Lego's) may have an apostrophe; it depends on what style you adhere to.)

But, to answer your question directly, there should be no apostrophes in that phrase. It's correct as-is.

NOTE: Sometimes you will see an apostrophe before a final -s that does indeed mark a plural. Ben Franklin (if I recall correctly) and his contemporaries would do this. There are also technical contexts where it might be done (although more often with past tense verbs (e.g. `malloc()'d`)).

Comment: "*But an apostrophe is never (correctly) used it English to mark a plural.*" That's not true. 80's, 50's,. M&M's, etc. (*EDIT:* after a search it seems more contentious than I thought. 90s seems to be generally preferred to 90's but there are style guides that allow the latter usage.)

Answer (score -2):

The rule on apostrophes on plurals applies if the word in question is a bona fide word as a plural.  My dictionary shows the plural of "why" with a simple "s." Ditto other words such as "wheres" "hows" "buts" "wherefores" "ands" and "ifs" but, oddly, no "therefores."

Comment: Two problems with this answer: (1) there's no "rule" on use of apostrophes in these situations, it's a matter of *style*, and (2) whether "rule" or style guide, it would apply to all words, whether "bona fide" or not. Hence *shouldnots* in preference to *mustnot's*.

Comment: A [good answer already posted here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/146468/167396) includes a link that references the Chicago Style Manual. See also the [Oxford Style Manual 2016](https://www.ox.ac.uk/public-affairs/style-guide?wssl=1), which says "Do not use an apostrophe to make a plural, even with a word/phrase that is not usually written in the plural or which appears clunky" and "To clarify something which will look odd if an s is added, consider italicising it or placing it in single quotation marks."