# Is an apostrophe appropriate for denoting plurality in ABC's?

Tags: apostrophe

Should one use an apostrophe to indicate that ABC's is plural or is it incorrect?

Comment: Related:[What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)

Comment: Also related: [The whys and the hows](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146348/the-whys-and-the-hows/146351#146351)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obsolete. Use ABCs, as recommended by Chicago Manual of Style, among many references.