# How would you pluralize a quote?

Tags: grammar, formatting

For example, how would I format this following sentence properly?

The others agree a little more heartily with “yeah”s and “it would”s.

Comment: You changed the question after you received an answer. Please don't do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plurals of quotations: “Chorus of ‘Hello’s”; “Ooh”s & “Ah”s](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71395/plurals-of-quotations-chorus-of-hello-s-ooh-s-ah-s)

Comment: Truss suggests: The others agree a little more heartily with _Yeah_”s and _It would_”s.

Answer (score 0):

The crowd jeered with cries of "boo" and "you suck."